# Не переходит к следущему элементу списка

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

имеется часть кода, которая отвечает за рассылку сообщений пользователям, но по какой-то причине цикл не переходит к следущему шагу, вот код:

```py
should_send = []

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def message_about_today():
    for i in vk.groups.getMembers(group_id="тут всё хорошо")['items']:
        name = ((vk.users.get(user_ids=i))[0])["first_name"]
        vk.messages.send(message='Да/Нет', user_id=i, random_id=0)
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                if event.to_me:
                    if event.text.lower() == "да":

                        global should_send
                        should_send.append(name)

                        vk.messages.send(message="Вы добавлены в список избранных, {}".format(name), user_id=i, random_id=0)

                    else:
                        vk.messages.send(message="Ну не хотите, как хотите", user_id=i, random_id=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

В строке `for event in longpoll.listen():` [бесконечный цикл](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/571bb92fba174c827aba874c190f0d4f05264120/vk_api/longpoll.py#L620), после попадания в него итерации цикла на уровень выше вы больше не дождётесь.

Одним из вариантов решения, без изменения текущей структуры метода, будет добавления `break` в тело `if event.to_me:`

Comment: Есть ли у вас предположение, как можно исправить мою проблему?

Comment: @shalor1k вообще polling должен идти первее, ведь он может понадобиться не только для этого метода.

Comment: Пробовал менять их местами, всё та же проблема